# What are the most essential things to include in a gardening journal?

Tags: vegetables, container-gardening

I am making a web application where people can create journals about their vegetable garden or flower garden. The information that these journals include can then be used by others who live nearby (it works with GPS).

These are the things i have right now:

Time until harvest,
sow time,
sprouting date,
harvest date

Anyone else know of something i could include?

Thank you

Comment: A grear idea to use GPS! I wonder, do you include local climates? Do users outside your country receive whatever instructions which may suit their locations?

Comment: well... it comes with a built in translation capability. English speaking foreigners are free to translate the entire website to their own language. As a reward they get there own country specific forum and i make them moderator of that forum

Comment: when the app is hopefully done in a month or 2 i will notify you all about it :)

Comment: meanwhile, 3 years later... But this time i'm _actually_ almost done :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd include somewhere to enter weather information other than the notes section - could track rainfall (per event, per time period), drought conditions, major weather events (storms with heavy rain, hail, strong winds - all of which can devastate a vegetable garden), last/late spring frost, first frost.

Also a pest section - insect, plant(s) affected, how the person treated (or did not treat); fungus, plant(s) affected, how the person treated (or did not treat). Same for birds and small mammals (children?)

It may be helpful to have a place to record where the seeds (or seedlings) where purchased and price paid.

If you're going to include flower gardens, then you could put in things like: plants acquired/where purchased/hardiness zones, along with the usual varietal information. You could also have a place to record plants that died/did poorly and those that did well. I think the place purchased could be very helpful since this is a local app.

Comment: Yeah. Weather information is important. Also if the garden is sleeping. It helps to see which time it is the best to sow (and compare to other years).

Comment: Another thought for Maurice - if you can store photos, a small photo album would be nice for people to show off their efforts :)

Comment: that will be included too @Jurp it will be like a photo set with a purpose, next to normal photos there will be so called 'growth stage' photos. Here you take photos at specific times: Once at seed sprouting so people who have never seen a seedling of that plant before know how it looks like and don't accidentaly remove the seedling when weeding out undesired weeds. The next photo will be of a flowering plant, and the next one of a fruit bearing plant. So now everyone knows at what stages the plant looks like. Also, could you check out my comment under Matthews post? I have a question thank yo

Answer (score 2):

What a great idea! You could include a notes section. For instance, it may be helpful for someone about to plant squash to know that the neighbor down the street had success in the native soil with BonBon but not with Gold Rush. Maybe a section on critters as well?

Comment: Rob that functionality will be in it too :) The name of that functionality is going to be called 'Social seedcalendar' and will work with GPS coordinates. Every journal will get the GPS coordinates of the author publishing the journal so that other people can search for all the journals that are for example within a 15 mile radius of them. They can filter too, for example fruit only, or cucumber only etc etc. Only the journals with a succesful outcome (harvest) will be included. But this is just one of many functionalities. The website is almost finished and is called www.seedcalendar.net

Comment: right now not yet online though… i hope to get it online by april/may

Comment: @Maurice Well keep us informed. I will be looking for the app in the app store.

Comment: it is going to be a website at first. kind of like davesgarden.com only better. mobile app will hopefully follow soon after

Comment: @Maurice Well I have never written a mobile app before myself but my job is building embedded Linux applications. From what I remember there are some great Python librarys for building Android apps.

Answer (score 2):

I would have two "journals". One about the plants, and one (which I think it maybe more important) about the work I do. *Sow* will be on both, but I'll do watering and a lot of other works. I would like to know how much work I put for my tomatoes, and as a reminder for the next year.

For me, checking what I did on previous years, is the most important thing. More than what the people which live near me are doing now. (but what they did in the past, and what plant they successfully sow is important).

Answer (score 1):

I recently  began putting my seed packet envelopes in a three ring binder using the same plastic sheets others store baseball cards in. This way I don't have to waste time writing down information that has already been recorded.  In addition if a certain seed from a certain catalogue works better than another I have the specs right at my finger tips.  I also have them organized by plant type, brassicas; cauliflower, broccoli, Brussel's sprouts together, flowers together, squash together etc.

What I plan on recording is what I plant in each bed this season. That way I can avoid over planting one crop in a bed.  I will also record planting dates and temperatures.  I am right on the line of zone 4 and 5 in Maine and our springs can be wildly unpredictable.  It will be nice to have my own weather data that is sight specific and not general like you will find through the national weather service.  I hope this helps.

Good Luck!

Comment: i'm on it! :) I have a question about the temperatures recording. I want to let the user be able to tell at what temperature his or her seed sprouted. The problem is though that temperatures can vary between te moment the seeds are sown and the moment the first seed has sprouted. So what should i let users do? Give the temperature of the day the seed sprouted? Or should the user enter an average temperature that is the average of all temperatures between seed date and sprout date. I also plan on putting a graph in the journal so temperatures can be recorded each day or each few days.

Comment: next i also would like the user to measure every few days the height and the width of the developing plant, i plan on plotting this data in the same graph as the temperature so you can easily see what an increase or decrease in temperature does to the plant growth rate during a given period. Does that sound nice? I could include other types of data too like rainfall, sunlight etc but i don't know if people are willing to record that many types of data. please tell me your opinion

Comment: For your temperature dilemma, you might consider having the user enter the low/high temperatures for each day. In the US, many gardeners have weather stations, many of which track this information.These temps (plus the difference between them and/or average) could be graphed and also plotted against seedling statistics, if you wanted to.

Comment: Now that I have thought about this a little bit more I may take two temperatures.  One is the atmosphere daily high and low which is easily captured on a thermometer.  The other is a soil temperature using a thermometer specifically for this purpose.  Soil temperature should stay more constant and rise over time.  If you do this take it at the same time each day probably the morning will be the best time to this before the sun heats it up.  I am not sure where you are located but Johnny's seed company has a lot of data on this I believe.